# Design a 2-D averaging filter that can decrease the effect of noise on the image

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-coder

Design a 2-D averaging filter that can decrease the effect of noise on the image “waves_noise.jpg”. You can use the image processing toolbox in MATLAB to read images, convert them from RGB to gray level, and do 2D convolution using MATLAB functions

Comment: You missed `D` in `Design` while copy-pasting for the title.

Comment: Is this homework? It sounds it's copied and pasted from a homework problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the imfilter command. This question is easy.